# Jenkins + Sonarqube - Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild

I'm trying to set up SonarQube (with Scanner for MSBuild) on Jenkins but gives me a fail, I have read other comments about this error and talks about SonarQube.Analysis.xml but it seems to be correct, Where should I make a look to realize that everything is correct?

http://pastebin.com/ghAxZPpj

this is my SonarQube config:

[image: JOB CONFIG]

Thanks you very much, If there's some necessary information, do not hesitate

**UPDATED**

> The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to
>   collect the required information about your projects. Possible causes:
>     1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
>     2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
>     3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to
>   complete SonarQube analysis.

Comment: The error looks more on the connection/AUTH between the jenkins jobs and the SONAR server where you are trying to run the analysis. You should check on the sonar server, on who can request for a analysis

Comment: I've been looking for some configuration but didn't get anything, question updated with more info...

Comment: The sonar server configuration will be available under jenkins configuration page.

Comment: Cannot resolve my issue... Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**, Finally got to update MSBuild from v4.0 (Default in Win10 from .net framework) to the last one MSBuild tools 2015... My first contact with Jenkins for Windows..